# Macro update in office365 for autofit code

Tags: office365

In Microsoft Office 365 (Office 16), I need to resize tables once converted from excel to word and my current code is not working. This is what I previously had:

```
Set WordTable - w.Doc.Tables(i + 14)
WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
```

Comment: "not working" is not enough of a description. Please give us some picture of what you're expecting, and how the actual result differs from your expectations.

Comment: Need some sort of actionable lead. Error statement or something

Comment: I  am getting a run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method.

t I am able to copy to word but when I try to run the autofit, it errors out and I am left with a big table on two pages – Danielle 1 hour ago